# How to explain the different behavior of `as.character()` on a `POSIXct` field: `select(foodate)` versus `$foodate`?

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the explanation for how these two different indexing methods result in different output from `as.character()` ?

```
> df <- data.frame(date=c( as.POSIXct("2021-01-15"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-16")))
> df
        date
1 2021-01-15
2 2021-01-16
> df$date %>% as.character()
[1] "2021-01-15" "2021-01-16"
> df %>% select(date) %>% as.character()
[1] "c(1610697600, 1610784000)"
```

I'd like to be able to use the dplyr syntax to convert a heterogeneous collection of fields to strings, so using `format()` to convert the dates would require some conditional logic. Is there a way to get the field with `select()` and still have `as.character()` return the formatted date  strings rather than the seconds-since-epoch?

Comment: `select` outputs a `list`-like structure (typically `tbl_df` or `data.frame`). `as.character(list(1:2))` shows the same thing. While it might be human-intuitive that `as.character(some_LIST)` should behave the same as `as.character(some_VECTOR)`, they are not the same. A vector is never nested, a `list` can be nested. So while it might seem obvious what `as.character(list(1:2))` should look like, what about `as.character(list(1:2, list(3:4, list(5:6), 7), 8))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `pull` instead of `select` as `select` returns a `data.frame/tibble` with one column while `pull` returns a `vector` and `as.character` expects a `vector` as input

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   pull(date) %>%
   as.character()
#[1] "2021-01-15" "2021-01-16"
```

---

With `tidyverse`, it is done within `mutate` to transform or modify or create a new column

```
df %>%
  select(date) %>%
  mutate(date = as.character(date))
```

---

The observed behavior is not related to `select` but the expectation of `as.character` input.  E.g.

```
as.character(df)
#[1] "c(1610686800, 1610773200)"
```

whereas, extracting a vector

```
as.character(df[,1])
#[1] "2021-01-15" "2021-01-16"
```

It is better to check the `str` before attempting

```
df %>%
  dplyr::select(date) %>% 
  str
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ date: POSIXct, format: "2021-01-15" "2021-01-16"
```